# How to import a java file into a javascript file

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I was wondering how to import my Java constant file into a Java script file and to call constant value into my js file.

The reason I need to import is I wish to assign this constant value as input value of a field

I would appreciate your help, Thank you, shamith

Comment: Simple answer : You can't do that. Instead create seperate JS for all constants across your application.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and Java programming languages have different syntax.

As such what you are asking is not possible. As Vimal already suggested, you should make another javascript file which will contain constants and include it in any other javascript files which require those constants.